# Track time duration for which video was played - Web, iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, html5-video, avaudioplayer, flash

I need a web based video player that provides "time duration for which a user played a video" and "instance at which the video stopped playing".

It would be great if it can provide details like the time at which the video was started (if he has skipped to a certain location when the video has started) and the stop time of the video.

Could anyone please suggest a ready made player available in market which provides all these information OR some alternate approach to achieve the same.

I want to achieve the same for iOS and Android devices. Is this something possible? And if yes please help me on its feasibility with Phonegap?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You won't need a speical player for this. The mediaelements audio and video already have a property called [played](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#dom-media-played).